# Visual Studio 2008: how to pause the running program to see a variable value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have started a long loop, and i dont want to start it over (been running 3 hours now, i calculated it to run only 1 hour instead), and i am afraid that my program is working incorrectly because its taking so long. I was too stupid to actually output any state values for myself (i didnt think it would take 3 damn hours).

So, is there some way to spy one specific variable value while the program was launched from visual studio in "Release" mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is attach to the running process

- Load the solution which represents the project
- Tools -> Attach to Process
- Select the running process and hit attach
- Hit the Pause Button on the IDE to stop the process or set a break point

At this point you will be broken in the debugger and able to inspect the running program

Comment: my program is the only program in the list where i CANT press the attach button, why is that? can i do anything more ?

Comment: @Rookie, hmm, it's possible it's running as an admin while you're just a local user. Is that possible?

Comment: it shows "adminstrator" for all of the programs in the list, and i also have adminstrator privileges on this account

Comment: @JaredPar: I bet that you are right. Rookie, you should try launching Visual Studio as Administrator and see if that helps.

Comment: @Rookie: Is it possible that it already has a debugger attached? That might explain why it isn't finishing. Is it using CPU? I don't believe Windows allows multiple debuggers to attach to the same program, so if it already has a debugger attached it couldn't attach another one.

Comment: yeah it has debugger attached to it (i think so), as it got launched from the visual studio automatically after it compiled it. so, im out of luck then?

Comment: @Rookie: Set a breakpoint and wait for it to get hit. That should work I think. There may also be a Pause button on the toolbar you can press. Don't press the Stop button though. That would end the program.

Comment: i cant find a pause button, but i managed to "pause" the program by F12 button. im really newbie on visual studio i practically only know how to compile the program :/ edit: i cant add breakpoints, tells "no symbols loaded"

Comment: @Rookie: If the toolbar is confusing, try looking in the Debug menu. Also, this *is* Visual Studio 2008 and not the Express edition, correct? The Express version is limited in a lot of ways.

Comment: @Rookie: No symbols loaded? That is bad, it will be impossible (unless you read machine code) to find the value of your variable. To make the symbols in Release mode you'd need to rebuild it after making sure the project properties for Generate Debug and Generate Program Database File (in Linker->Debugging) were set.

Comment: nope, its not express edition. the only button that has the pause icon is in the debug menu with name "break all" i pressed it and tried to add breakpoints, but it still says the same "no symbols loaded" on those breakpoints. edit: oh well, i guess i just start over :/

Answer (score 1):

Attach the debugger to the running program.  Set a breakpoint.  Bask in the glory.

Of course, this all assumes you built PDBs.  If you didn't, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: @Rookie PDB = Program DataBase

Answer (score 0):

If the program was launched from Visual Studio it is possible that it already has a debugger (Visual Studio) attached to the process.

Visual Studio will have VCR/DVD looking buttons on the toolbar for Go, Stop, Pause, etc. Press the Stop button, or go into the Debug menu and choose Break All.